# Fixing line-height or gap issues with flex container and artificial line break

Tags: css, flexbox, line-breaks

I am using a flex container and an artificial line break to break words when desired.  I never realized that it was causing extra gap space between lines.

As you can see in the example, the space between lines after the line break after the word HOW is taller than the other distances between lines.

The parent div could be any size at any time in both the width and height, and the children will always be vertically centered and could left or right or center justified, so unless I am missing something Flex seems to be ideal.

```css
.outer-container {
height:200px;
width:200px;
}

.flex-container {
  display:flex;
  gap:.2em;
  font-size:20px;
  width:100%;
height:100%;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  white-space:pre-line;
  align-content:center;
  justify-content:center;
  
}

.flex-item {
  background:red;
  padding:2px;
}

.linebreak {
  display:flex;
   
    flex-direction: column; 
     flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer-container">
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">Hi</div>
  <div class="flex-item">There</div>
  <div class="flex-item">How</div>
  <div class="linebreak"></div>
  <div class="flex-item">Are</div>
   <div class="flex-item">You</div>
     <div class="flex-item">Everyone</div>
       <div class="flex-item">Here</div>
         <div class="flex-item">is Fine</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not only taller, but it's at *2x* (`.4em` to be exact) distant. Of course it's an intended behavior -- there's `.2em` gap among all flex children per your stylesheet. What exactly do you want to "address" here?

Comment: Remove class `linebreak` and all will be as expected.

Comment: @Gerard True, but then if my flexbox happens to be wider than the current size (and while I have it at a fixed size for this example it won't always be), I won't have the intended break at that point.

Comment: @msrumon I would like the space to be the same height as the space between the other words.  Happy to clarify in my question, if you can let me know which part is not clear. thx.

Comment: I added some more context for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the grid gap and put .1em margin on the items.

```css
.flex-container {
  display:flex;
  font-size:20px;
  width:200px;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  white-space:pre-line;
}

.flex-item {
  background:red;
  padding:2px;
  margin: .1em;
}

.linebreak {
  display:flex;
   
    flex-direction: column; 
     flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">Hi</div>
  <div class="flex-item">There</div>
  <div class="flex-item">How</div>
  <div class="linebreak"></div>
  <div class="flex-item">Are</div>
   <div class="flex-item">You</div>
     <div class="flex-item">Everyone</div>
       <div class="flex-item">Here</div>
         <div class="flex-item">is Fine</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like the might make the most sense.  Let me test it out.

Comment: yes, this seems to be the solution.  thank you.